# Our basketball team has 10 players. We need to divide into two teams of 5 for an intra-squad scrimmage. In how many ways can we do this

Tags: combinatorics

Our basketball team has 10 players, including Steve and Danny. We need to divide into two teams of 5 for an intra-squad scrimmage. In how many ways can we do this without restrictions?

I'm not sure I know how to do this. It isn't 10 choose 5.

Comment: Pick who the four other people on the team with the shortest player are.

Answer (score 5):

Choosing players

Team 1: ABCDE

Team 2: FGHIJ

leads to the exact same matchup as

Team 1: FGHIJ

Team 2: ABCDE.

So the answer is $\frac{1}{2} \binom{10}{5}$.  You were close.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out in the post as well that $\frac{1}{2}\binom{10}{5}=\binom{9}{4}$ for completeness.